# How to add new line character in text getting from database

Tags: java, html, spring, string, spring-data

I have a table and in one of the column I have long text in which I want to replace all ";" by "\n* " when I am displaying the text in a browser.

I tried:

```
String ingredients = recipe.getIngredients().replace(";","\n* ");
recipe.setIngredients(ingredients);
```

as well as:

```
String ingredients = recipe.getIngredients().replace(";","<br>* ");
recipe.setIngredients(ingredients);
```

But in the browser I have something like this:

```
foo1* foo2* foo3
```

or, for the second version:

```
foo1<br>* foo2<br>* foo3
```

And I would like have text like this:

```
foo1
*foo2
*foo3
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: I would start by looking in the browser's inspect pane for the actual HTML code generated. I imagine there are some escape characters in use. Could you please post what the actual html code is, rather than the way it's rendered on screen?